# AD Group Membership Export to separate columns

Tags: csv, active-directory, xlsx, powershell-ise

I'm looking to make a (hopefully) simple CSV or XLSX that I can use to compare two users' AD group memberships via PowerShell ISE. Currently, it's a bit extensive, though mostly this has been the "bread & butter" of the script:

```
Get-ADUser -Identity $User1 -Properties 'name' | Select-Object -Property Name | Export-CSV $CSVFile
try{Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $User1 | select name | Export-CSV $CSVFile -Append}
catch{Write-Host "Unable to locate $User1. Please check the ID and retry. $User1 will not be included in export if completed."}

{DBEngine.Idle} #For assistance in processing a break in the names visually on screen.

Get-ADUser -Identity $User2 -Properties 'name' | Select-Object -Property Name | Export-CSV $CSVFile -Append
try{Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $User2 | select name | Export-CSV $CSVFile -Append}
catch{Write-Host "Unable to locate $User2. Please check the ID and retry. $User2 will not be included in export if completed."}
Write-Host "
AD Groups assigned to $User1 and $User2 will also be exported to $CSVFile, unless halted. Check folder contents.
"
```

I have Read-Host messages to define the values for $User1 & $User2, and a predefined name convention for $CSVFile. What I receive is just a single-column list containing the name of the user, then their group memberships in whatever order, so I manually sort groups for the first user, then do the same for the second. Afterwards, I manually move the $User2 name and groups out to a different column. So my output looks like this in a CSV file:

```
|User1.Name|
|AD_Group_2|
|AD_Group_3|
|AD_Group_1|
|User2.Name|
|AD_Group_3|
|AD_Group_1|
|AD_Group_2|
```

So it's a bit of a hunt when there are a significantly different number of groups per user. What I'd like to have returned is something like this:

```
|User1.Name|User2.Name|
|AD_Group_1|AD_Group_1|
|AD_Group_2|AD_Group_2|
|AD_Group_3|AD_Group_3|
```

If the columns are not in alphabetic order, I'm not too worried, because I can fairly easily sort it out as long as the names are at the top. Getting the information in different columns is my main goal.

*Edit: Building to separate Worksheets would also be fine, too. Just somewhere that can be easily referenced and sorted.*

Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Your request is highly unusual. You can do anything with PowerShell or any other language but you should always follow standards and this is really not standard.

The first part of the code is the standard way of doing things. You can use that to do the compare on PowerShell instead of visually on Excel for instance. Check the output of $output1 after running the code.

Having said that, here's what you want...

```
$User1 = "user1" # use SamAccountName or Read-Host
$User2 = "user2" # use SamAccountName or Read-Host
# add more as needed

#create array of all users
$users = @($User1, $User2)

# get information of all users from AD
$allUsers = $users | Get-ADUser

# gathers all users and groups from AD
$output1 = @()
foreach ( $user in $allUsers )
{
    # new object
    $out = New-Object -TypeName PSObject
    # user
    $out | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name User -Value $user.Name
    # all groups
    $out | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Groups -Value (($user | Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership).Name)
    # add user details to object
    $output1 += $out
}

#$output #check here

# number of users in list
$maxusers = $output1.Count

# find user with more groups
$max = 0
$output1 | ForEach-Object { if ($_.Groups.Count -gt $max){ $max = $_.Groups.Count } }

# creates alternative output
$output2 = @()
for ( $x = 0; $x -lt $max; $x++ )
{
    # new object
    $out = New-Object -TypeName PSObject
    # iterate all groups
    for  ( $y = 0; $y -lt $maxusers; $y++ )
    {
        # if the group is populated for the user, add it as a property
        if ( $output1[$y].Groups[$x] )
        {
            $out | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name $output1[$y].User -Value $output1[$y].Groups[$x]
        }
    }
    # add user details to object
    $output2 += $out
}

$output2 | FT # what you are looking for


$output2 | Export-Csv "C:\folder\out.csv"
```